# Copy 'N' lines from one file to another in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting

Essentially what I am attempting to do is read 'n' number of lines from a file and then write them to a separate file. This program essentially should take a file that has 100 lines and separate that file into 50 separate files.

```
def main():
     from itertools import islice
     userfile = raw_input("Please enter the file you wish to open\n(must be in this   directory): ")
     file1 = open(userfile, "r+")
     #print "Name: ", file1.name
     #print "Closed or not", file1.closed
     #print "Opening mode: ", file1.mode
     #print "Softspace flag: ", file1.softspace
     jcardtop = file1.read(221);
     #print jcardtop
     n = 2
     count = 0
     while True:
         next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
         print next_n_lines
         count = count + 1
         fileout = open(str(count)+ ".txt", "w+")
         fileout.write(str(jcardtop))
         fileout.write(str(next_n_lines))
         fileout.close()
         break
         if not next_n_lines:
              break
```

I do have the file printing as well to show what is in the variable next_n_lines.

```
*['\n', "randomtext' more junk here\n"]
```

I would like it instead to look like

```
 randomtext' more junk here
```

Is this a limitatoin of the islice function? Or am I missing a portion of the syntax?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you saying you don't want it to be in a list? Do you just need to `''.join(next_n_lines)`?

Comment: @nmichaels I am trying to print (literal?), basically the \n characters are pulled form a read file (new lines) and I to write those new lines to a separate file.

Essentially the task would be to copy 2 lines at a time from a file, and paste them to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you call `str()` or `print`, you want to `''.join(next_n_lines)` instead:

```
print ''.join(next_n_lines)
```

and

```
fileout.write(''.join(next_n_lines))
```

You can store the flattened string in a variable if you don't want to call join twice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
f = open(userfile,"r")
start = 4
n_lines = 100

for line in f.readlines()[start:(start + n_lines)]:
    print line
    #do stuff with line
```

or maybe this rough, yet effective code:

```
f = open(userfile,"r")
start = 4
end = start + 100

count = start
while count != end:
    for line in f.readlines()[count:(count + 2)]:
         fileout = open(str(count)+ ".txt", "w+")
         fileout.write(str(line))
         fileout.close()
         count = count + 2
```